# jquery $.post post data with php header to next page

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem using Jquery $.post to check data without refresh the page and print out any error on page div

I can't header(location); to next page if all data are correct.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function get(){
            $('#error').hide();

            $.post('./parts/signup_data.php', 
                        {firstname:signup.firstname.value, lastname:signup.lastname.value, 
                        email:signup.email.value, re_email:signup.re_email.value, 
                        password:signup.password.value, re_password:signup.re_password.value,
                        age:signup.age.value, 
                        gender:$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val(),
                        },      
                        function(output){$('#error').html(output).fadeIn(50);}
                  )             
        }      
    </script>
```

Page will check all data without refresh and print out error on div tag

if all data are correct. it will insert the data into DB

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp_user (email, password, firstname, lastname, age, gender, date, confirm_code)VALUES ('$email','$password','$firstname', '$lastname', '$age', '$gender', '$date', '$confirm_code')");

header('Location:confirm.php');
```

the problem is the page didn't head to next page.
it print out all page's information in div tag

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: header() won't work if something is already outputted to browser

Comment: I suggest you avoid using the dated `mysql_*` functions; they're [highly
discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query). More modern alternatives are available and better 
maintained. Instead, consider learning about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), and that you use either [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). When used strictly, they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part, which thus become heaps easier and (as a by-product) 
safer to use. Check out [this PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send something (eg, a JSON object) back to the Javascript code that tells it which page to go to.

The Javascript code in the success callback would then check the result from the server to see if it's a URL or an error message, and set `location.href` or display the message as appropriate.